# Why won't my pending dividends show up in Robinhood account?

Tags: stocks, dividends, robinhood

BP is supposed to pay dividends tomorrow but when in Robinhood whenever I navigate to History -> Filter -> Dividends it says: `When you receive your first dividend, it will show up here`.  Isn't there supposed display a pending status or something?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure that the dividend is paid tomorrow? https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/summary?s=BP.:LSE suggests that it goes ex-div tomorrow but the dividend isn't paid until the 21st of June

Comment: Ex-dividend is tomorrow.  I suspect that the OP used the wrong description.

Comment: @BobBaerker yes I did, I just realized!

Answer (score 3):

BP goes ex-dividend for tomorrow for 61 cents.  The payment date is June 21st.

Every broker I have used offers a look up feature to check the Declaration, Ex-div, Record and Payment dates for securities.  See if you can find that feature at Robinhood. If not, there are many web sites that offer it. None (brokers) provided notification of a pending dividend.

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t get the dividend until tomorrow, nothing will show in your history today. Check again in a couple days and you should see it.

Comment: Robinhood does indeed show pending dividends (i.e. between ex-div and payment). OP made a mistake and tomorrow is the ex-dividend date, not the payment date.